# transition from one scene to another

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

I have three NSArrays named *a, b, c* and another NSMutableArray named *na*.

The 3 arrays contain the elements imagename.image.

When the button is taped the 3 arrays are merged to the mutable array *na*. Again the array gets split. This process is repeated and after the third tap the 10th element of *na* should be displayed on another view controller.

I have set a counter *j* and I need the steps when *j==3*.

```
- (IBAction)selection1:(id)sender { 
    na = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; 

    [na addObjectsFromArray:b]; 
    [na addObjectsFromArray:a]; 
    [na addObjectsFromArray:c]; 
    if(j==3) { 
        j=1; //I need the code for this part 
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"SendInfo" sender: self]; 
    } else { 
        j++; 
        img1.image=[na objectAtIndex:0]; 
        img2.image=[na objectAtIndex:3]; 
        img3.image=[na objectAtIndex:6]; 
        img4.image=[na objectAtIndex:1];
        img5.image=[na objectAtIndex:4]; 
        img6.image=[na objectAtIndex:7]; 
        img7.image=[na objectAtIndex:2]; 
        img8.image=[na objectAtIndex:5]; 
        img9.image=[na objectAtIndex:8]; 

        a=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:img1.image,img2.image,img3.image, nil]; 
        b=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:img4.image,img5.image,img6.image, nil]; 
        c=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:img7.image,img8.image,img9.image, nil]; 
    } 
}
```

Can you help me? I am new to xcode.

Comment: How does the array get split? by what rules? So you press the button and na contains [a, b, c]. How do you split it afterwards and when do you split it? on another tap? As it is, your question is very, very unclear

Comment: Split in the sense again the arrays are again initialized with images.I can copy paste the code

Comment: - (IBAction)selection1:(id)sender {
   na = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
   [na addObjectsFromArray:b];
    [na addObjectsFromArray:a];
    [na addObjectsFromArray:c];
   if(j==3)
   {
       j=1;
      //I need the code for this part
      
       [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"SendInfo" 
                                 sender: self];
   }

Comment: else
   {
       j++;
       img1.image=[na objectAtIndex:0];
       img2.image=[na objectAtIndex:3];
       img3.image=[na objectAtIndex:6];
       img4.image=[na objectAtIndex:1];

Comment: img5.image=[na objectAtIndex:4];
      img6.image=[na objectAtIndex:7];
      img7.image=[na objectAtIndex:2];
      img8.image=[na objectAtIndex:5];
      img9.image=[na objectAtIndex:8];

Comment: a=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:img1.image,img2.image,img3.image, nil];
      b=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:img4.image,img5.image,img6.image, nil];
      c=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:img7.image,img8.image,img9.image, nil];
  }
}

Comment: http://pastebin.com/db9mM84V I pieced together your code here in case someone else needs it. Next time edit your question instead of breaking it into comments.

Comment: Anyway, I'm still not certain I can understand exactly. So, when j is 3, you would like to open a new view controller and pass the 10th element of na to it? Is this correct?

Comment: @BBog you can edit the question yourself not pyr code somewhere else

Comment: @Mark I know, but I already edited his question once, before he posted the code and I didn't know for sure if I could do it again before the first edit was approved